# "as" or "to be"

Tags: complementation, infinitive-clauses

I saw the first sentence in a letter. do you think I can use the second sentence instead ? What is the difference in the meanings ?

1- I can not accept your letter **to be** a compliant notice in accordance with the requirements of our regulations.

2- I can not accept your letter **as** a compliant notice in accordance with the requirements of our regulations.

Answer (score 2):

"To be" in the infinitive form of the verb **be**, and therefore may be used following a noun or direct object to indicate what use that object might have. In this case, the letter is the noun, and the verb "to be" indicates it would be used for something (except as previously stated, it can't be used for that purpose -- but that doesn't matter from a grammar point of view).

Clear as mud? This link might help: http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/verbs/infinitive-verb.html

To answer the first part of your question, yes! You may replace "to be" with "as", because in this case you are using "as" [as a preposition meaning "being"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/as). That is perfectly correct.

There really is no difference in the two meanings, as used in this sentence. I believe the sentence constructed with "to be" is slightly more formal and sounds more official. Your construction with "as" is more readable and doesn't sound quite so [pompous](http://www.yourdictionary.com/pompous).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the second; *accept* ordinarily takes *that* clauses ("accept that your letter is"), not infinitive clauses. But your *as* version clearly states that you reject the letter itself, not merely your correspondent's assertion that it is adequate.

Both versions are unnecessarily wordy: *compliant*, *in accordance with* and *requirements* all say pretty much the same thing. It may be that *compliant notice* is a specific sort of communication required by the regulation; if that is the case, it should be marked with quotes, and you could say something like:

> I cannot accept your letter as "compliant notice" under our regulations.

If that is not the case you can simplify even further:

> I cannot accept your letter as notice under our regulations.

Moreover, all of these are quite stiff and are likely to be taken as arrogant or hostile. You could soften this by writing something like:

> I'm afraid your letter doesn't provide the notice our regulations require.